# Which collocation should I use with "replacement"?

Tags: word-choice

I am doing an English language test.
Can you help me with this question?

> “We will deduct $5.95 from your available funds **__________** of the
>   lost Gift Card.”
>
> a)   upon the replacement
>   b)   is replacing
>   c)   during the replacement
>   d)   as we issue you the replacement

Is it A or D?

Comment: @ Peter..The answer is a

Comment: I'd say it's d) :)

Comment: 'A' is simpler and makes more sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say a) except it should really be "upon replacement of the lost Gift Card." The echo of 'as /we/' in d) makes it an appealing choice, but the phrase as a whole is awkward when d) is substituted.

Answer (score 1):

The issue with this statement is context.

If the funds are being deducted while they are getting around to replacing the lost gift card, I would say that it would be C ("We will deduct $5.95 from your available funds *during the replacement* of the lost Gift Card."). This is because "during the replacement" would refer to while the act of replacing it is going on (that is, while they are sourcing a new card to use as a replacement).

If the funds are being deducted at the same time that they replace the gift card, it would be D ("We will deduct $5.95 from your available funds *as we issue you the replacement* of the lost Gift Card.") This is because "as we issue you the replacement" says that it is happening *as* the other is happening.

If the funds are being deducted only after the lost gift card has been replaced, then it would be A ("We will deduct $5.95 from your available funds *upon the replacement* of the lost Gift Card." This is because of the fact that they will deduct the money "upon the replacement of the lost Gift Card", meaning that it is only once the gift card has been replaced that they will deduct the money.

Without more context, I would most likely say that it is A due to the subject matter (I would expect that they would take the money out of an account after the gift card has been replaced, not before or during)

Hopefully this helps, unfortunately I don't have any citations other than being a native speaker. One of the confusing things about language is how often it just becomes a case of "gut feeling".

Answer (score -1):

I'd also go with (A). Option A implies that they are not liable to replace the lost Gift card but if they do,they would deduct the said amount. Option D implies that they will do(almost immediately) the replacement AND they will deduct the said amount.